# ServiceStack.Razor + F#

Tags: razor, f#, servicestack

How may I use ServiceStack.Razor in an F# project ?

I have added a reference to the ServiceStack.Razor (which seems to pose no issue on Windows but raise an exception on Mono on Mac for some reason).

Regardless, once this is added, and after registering the plugin, I have tried adding the cshtml files to he project. However this fails because the F# compiler cannot compile them. I have also tried to not add them to the compilation, but it doesn't work either.

Should I add an app.config file or something ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do that. Here is [visual studio template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/278caff1-917a-4ac1-a552-e5a2ce0f6e1f) if you are using Visual Studio. Else have a look at [my project](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku) where I am using F# with servicestack and razor successfully. And also able to host it over heroku. Please let me know if you need anything else.